# Antiforgery token and resource not available

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC web application published to azure. Due to the inclusion of @html.antiforgerytoken() in edit view I was getting error whenever I click edit actionlink. So I removed that code in the view and published again. Now I'm seeing the error like 'resource not available'. My question is the error might be because of some other problem or is there any link with removal of this antiforgery token in the view? Please help me out of this. Do I need to make any other change in my code?

Comment: When using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` do you then also have the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute set on your (`[HttpPost]`) `ActionResult`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is the error might be because of some other problem or is there any link with removal of this antiforgery token in the view?

As Lasse said, when you using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, you also need have 
`[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute on your `[HttpPost]` ActionResult.

So, if you want to [remove the antiforgery token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view), you also need to remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute.

Actually, `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is a security feature to help [protect your application against cross-site request forgery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.2).